# Comment text area in single blog post and show comments if approved

Tags: comments, templates, single

I'm modifying some existing code and trying to add the ability for user to leave comments on single post and then echo those comments based on approval.  I need to add right below `<?php  the_content(); ?>`
What is the code I need to add below this to get comments?

Comment: add this `if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {comments_template();}`

Answer (score 0):

Right bellow the content (single post)

```
<?php if (function_exists('paged_comments_template')) paged_comments_template(); else comments_template(); ?>
```

And the approval you need change in the wordpress panel.

Answer (score 0):

In the content.php, add code like this:

```
if ( ! post_password_required() && ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) ) :
        ?>
        <span class="comments-link"><?php comments_popup_link( __( 'Leave a comment', '$text_domain' ), __( '1 Comment', '$text_domain' ), __( '% Comments', '$text_domain' ) ); ?></span>
        <?php
            endif;
```

And before endwhile in single.php, this:

```
if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) {
                        comments_template();
                    }
                endwhile;
            ?>
```

View the single.php and content.php files in the Twenty Fourteen theme for a guide.

[Moderate comments](http://codex.wordpress.org/Comment_Moderation) using the Discussion settings.